# Eigenvectors of a repeated eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a matrix $A$ that is expressed as
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
 6&  0&  3&  0&  3&0 \\ 
 2&  -6&  1&  -3&  1&-3 \\ 
 0&  0&  6&  0&  0& 0\\ 
 0&  0&  2&  -6&  0&0 \\ 
 0&  0&  0&  0&  3& 0\\ 
 0&  0&  0&  0&  1& -3
\end{bmatrix}$$
 I now want to find the eigenvectors that correspond to a repeated eigenvalue. For example, I consider the eigenvalues $\lambda =6$ which is repeated twice.

Let's denote $x=[x_1,..,x_6]^T$ the eigenvectors of this eigenvalue.

First, I calculate
$$\ (A - 6I_6)^2 x=0 $$
After that, I get the solution

$$ \left\{\begin{matrix}
-x_1 + 6x_2 -x_3 + 6x_4=0\\ 
-x_3 + 6x_4 =0\\
x_5=0\\
x_6 =0
\end{matrix}\right.$$
However, when I check the results by using Matlab. It gives
$x=[0.9864 \; 0.1644 \;0 \;0 \;0 \;0]^T$ and $x=[-0.9864\; -0.1644 \;0 \;0 \;0 \;0]^T$.

Could you please point out what is wrong in my thinking?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Your 'solution' is not yet finished, you first have to calculate the eigenvectors. Then note that if $x$ is an eigenvector, then $ax$ is also an eigenvector for every $a\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Searching for **proper** eigenvectors of the eigenvalue $\lambda=6$ you have to solve the equation:
$$
(A-6I)x=0
$$that gives the system
$$
\begin{cases}
3x_3+3x_5=0\\
2x_1-12x_2+x_3-3x_4+x_5-3x_6=0\\
2x_3-12x_4=0\\
-3x_5=0\\
x_5-9x_6=0
\end{cases}
$$
that has solution: $x_1=6x_2 \quad \forall \quad x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6 \in \mathbb{R}$
So, the eigenspace has dimension $1$ ( the eigenvector $v_{\lambda=6}=(6,1,0,0,0,0)^T$).

Comment: If there is only one eigenvector,  how can I define the Jordan form?

Comment: Your matrix have the other eigenvalues: $\lambda=-6$ with algebraic multiplicity $2$ and geometric multiplicity $1$ and $\lambda=\pm 3$ each with algebraic and geometric multiplicity $1$ . So the the Jordan form has these six values on the diagonal, and an $1$ upper the diagonal in the two places right and upper the doubles eigenvalues. ( see  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Jordan+form+%7B%7B6%2C0%2C3%2C0%2C3%2C0%7D%2C%7B2%2C-6%2C1%2C-3%2C1%2C-3%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C6%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C2%2C-6%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C3%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C-3%7D%7D.

Comment: The calculus of the generalized eigenvectors is a bit more tricky. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector.

Comment: Yeah. In my solution, I am trying to calculate generalized eigenvectors for $\lambda =6$ . But It seems that I am confusing

Answer (score 0):

The eigenvalue $6$ has algebraic multiplicity $2$, but geometric multiplicity $1$: the null space of $A - 6 I$ is one-dimensional, spanned
by $(6,1,0,0,0,0)^T$.  $(0,0,6,1,0,0)^T$ is in the null space of $(A-6I)^2$ but is not an eigenvector of $A$.

Numerically, this is an unstable situation: a very small perturbation of the matrix is likely to have two distinct (but very close) eigenvalues, each with their own eigenvectors, rather than a double eigenvalue.  Thus Matlab, which uses numerical methods, is likely to be unreliable in this situation.

Comment: Could you tell me how to select two eigenvectors corresponding to $\lambda =6$? I mean that how can I select the second one?

Comment: There don't exist two linearly independent eigenvectors corresponding to $\lambda = 6$.

Comment: Haizzz. Now, it makes me confuse. In this case, how can I define the Jordan form?